# Return to waiting terminal after finished with GUI app (for external mergetool)

Tags: shell, git, gui, process-management

When using an external GUI app for `git mergetool`, the shell sits in the background waiting patiently. When I save and close the GUI window, the shell returns to the foreground and git is main app again. I'm trying to find out how that is done so I can use it for a script I'm writing.

I've inspected the env, the `SHLVL` is incremented, `TEXTDOMAIN` is set to `git`, and git inserts itself into things like `PATH` and `GIT_EXEC_PATH`, but I don't see how the terminal and the app collude to return to the starting point *when only a window/document has been closed*.

Sorry if that's vague, I just can't see how this is done. If it was linked to the quiting of the app I could see a way, but I'm stumped. Perhaps it's something set in the GUI app, so I'm looking at the source for [Meld](https://github.com/GNOME/meld/) but I've yet to find it.

Any insights or places to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: "If it was linked to the quiting of the app" .. it is. Rather, to the quitting of the process that was started by git. It won't work well with a tool where the process started by git then hands off to some other process and dies (like, say, gedit).

Comment: @muru "where the process started by git then hands off to some other process and dies (like, say, gedit)." But isn't that what mergetool does? Git starts hands off the files to diff to an external tool, could be gedit, and when that window is closed then it's back to git in the terminal, regardless of whether gedit is still running or was running before git ran the tool (and all its windows will be under 1 pid). I must be missing something obvious, which is why my question feels so flabby :/

Comment: Ah, got it. Git has a set of supported mergetools, and `meld` is one of them. It gets the output using the `--output` option: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/meld#L13. It probably watches the output file, and so figures out when meld exited.